# Magento Varnish Cache save()

Tags: magento, caching, save, varnish

We use Varnish Phoenix PageCache extension in our Magento webshop. Every night we are importing products with an self developed import, using $product->save() after setting attributes we get through an *.csv file.

**Problem:** I noticed the import process really slowing down. After some debugging i found out that every save() takes about 2 seconds! That is way to slow. 
I already deactivated purging the product varnish cache after save actions, and commented out these lines in PageCache config.xml:

```
<catalog_product_save_after>
    <observers>
        <phoenix_varnishcache>
            <class>varnishcache/observer</class>
            <method>purgeCatalogProduct</method>
        </phoenix_varnishcache>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_save_after>
```

The import is still really slow.
Has somebody an idea how i could manage this?

Comment: Indexing create issue every time product is save and index is alos run so set your index on manual update

Comment: I forgot to mention: we also use an asych indexing extension, so i think this isn't a reindex issue.

Comment: @s4lfish like Mufaddal has said, set your indexed on manual update.
In order to debug it further, can u tell us how much time it was taking before the pageCache module??
`Product->save()` generally takes time, as it saves the data and reindex every affected index (catalog_category_product, product_attribute, stock, product_flat). Moreover you can turn on slow log for queries and slow log for slow scripts (if you are using php-fpm) to identify which method or query is taking that much time.